# How do I change the class of a forms parent if they enter it wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a  at the moment in order to add a search feature to my site. I want them to enter a number that starts with 765611 and then has 11 numbers after that; if they type in a correct number, it will run the below script:

```
    var a = document.getElementById('search');
a.addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var b = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
    window.location.href = 'thecopperkings.co.uk'+b;

});
```

If they enter a wrong number (i.e. one that does not start with 765611 *and* have 11 numbers proceeding it) the background of the div will flash red for two seconds (I assume the way this would be done is by adding a temporary class value which has a red background) with a transition as well, and the above code wouldn't run.

I'm pretty terrible (and new) to JS but looking at other peoples code and my basic knowledge, I assume it would have to be something along the lines of this:

```
var search = document.getElementByID('search');
a.addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
if document.getElementByID('searchbar').value = "765611[0-9]{11}$" {
    e.preventDefault();
    var b = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
    window.location.href = 'thecopperkings.co.uk'+b;
}
else {
**SET THE FORM'S CLASS TO "RED"?**
}
```

What is the best and most efficient way of doing this?

```js
    var a = document.getElementById('search');
    a.addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var b = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
        window.location.href = 'thecopperkings.co.uk'+b;

    });
```

```html
        <div>
            <form class="search" id="search" method="get" action="html/player.html">
                <input type="text" placeholder="What is your SteamID?" id="searchbar" name="id" maxlength="17">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below answer.

working example can be found here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dabeer88/x7qu3ds0/21/)

Add class red as **`.red { background-color:red !important;}`**

```js
   

    var a = document.getElementById('search');

function appendClass(elementId, classToAppend){
    var oldClass = document.getElementById(elementId).getAttribute("class");
    if (oldClass.indexOf(classToAppend) == -1)
    {
      document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute("class", oldClass+ " "+classToAppend);
    }
}

function removeClass(elementId, classToRemove){
    var oldClass = document.getElementById(elementId).getAttribute("class");
    if (oldClass.indexOf(classToRemove) !== -1)
    {       document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute("class",oldClass.replace(classToRemove,''));
    }
}
    a.addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var b = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
        //regular expression to match your criteria and test the sample value
    if(/^765611[0-9]{11}$/.test(b)) {
          alert('success -> '+ b );
     window.location.href = 'thecopperkings.co.uk'+b;
    } else {
         //append the class red for searchid which is in form element
         appendClass('search','red');
          //remove the red class after 2sec(2000milliseconds)
         window.setTimeout(function(){removeClass('search','red');},2000);
        }

    });
```

```html
        <div>
            <form class="search" id="search" method="get" action="html/player.html">
                <input type="text" placeholder="What is your SteamID?" id="searchbar" name="id" maxlength="17">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var patt = new RegExp("765611[0-9]{11}$");
var searchbar  = document.getElementByID('searchbar');
var searchForm = document.getElementByID('search');

if( patt.test(searchbar.value) ){
    searchForm.classlist.remove('error');
    // do your magic
} else{
    searchForm.classlist.add('error');
    // And maybe an alert or notice for the user
}
```

Also, check out the html5 input attribute [`pattern=""`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern)

Comment: This doesn't work for me because either way when I press enter it redirects to the page it's supposed to be going to (i.e. .../html/player.html?id="whatever they enter") so it doesn't get the opportunity to change the background. I would like it so that if they don't enter using the right parameters, then it's not going to redirect them to that link and will instead flash the box red. Also, thinking about it now do I even need the script I posted? I've never made a search bar before so I assumed I needed it, but with testing I didn't?

Comment: This is because you havent stopped the form from submitting, you still have to use the preventDefault().

Comment: Would this code work to fix that?:


var patt = new RegExp("765611[0-9]{11}$");
var searchBar  = document.getElementByID('searchbar');
var searchForm = document.getElementByID('search');

searchForm.addEventListener('onKeyDown', function(e) {
    if( patt.test(searchbar.value) ){
        searchForm.classlist.remove('error');
    } else{
        searchForm.classlist.add('error');
    }
}

Comment: Managed to do it all in html thanks to your pattern suggestion! Thank you very much :) For anyone else having the same issue check out https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: I've already added documentation in my answer :) If this answers your question, please mark it as a solution so that other can see it too